# Hover menu on phone : it goes at the top when taping

Tags: ios, wordpress, hover, mobile-phones, touchstart

On my website (still in beta version), here : http://www.collectifsaga.com/X/wordpress/fr/home-fr, I have a menu hover (filters for the grid)

I have a problem on phones (I have an iPhone, I don't know if there is problem on other devices) with that hover menu.
The hover is working well (with `:active` in the CSS) and by adding this in the `<head>` : `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);`

This problem is, when I tap on the hover menu, the page goes directly to the top, even if I'm on the middle or bottom of it. And that's quite tiring

Do you know how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault();
```

so you would have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><img src="http://www.collectifsaga.com/_SAGA/_graph/icone/plus.svg" width="160px"></a>
```

inside your link that shows your menu when u tap on it. You could also use span instead of "a" for it, might even be better solution as thats not link.